# Cannot connect to Magnolia after installation

Tags: magnolia

I am new to Magnolia. I installed the bundle and tried to run it from the command prompt. The server is getting started, but while calling the URL http://localhost:8080 (TomCat port 8090), it is not loading:

[image]

The bundle I downloaded is [this one](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.public.releases//info/magnolia/bundle/magnolia-community-demo-bundle/5.5.7/magnolia-community-demo-bundle-5.5.7-tomcat-bundle.zip).

Comment: your server is not up. there would be error messages in catalina.log file and/or console

Comment: did you remove or rename the ROOT-webapp in your tomcat/webapps folder? if you named it anything else than root, then this will be your context path

Answer (score 0):

That bundle seems to work for me, so I wonder if you have some logs you could show us? Perhaps *catalina.out*?

Also might be helpful to see the output of the following commands:

```
lsof -i:8080
```

and

```
ps aux | grep -E 'magnolia|tomcat'
```

Thanks for your help!